# How can I find the PDF of a function of a random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Lets say I have some function, say $f(x)$.  I'll define a random variable $p$ with some distribution between some bounds $a$ & $b$. How can I find the distribution of $f(p)$?

For example. With $f(x)=x^2$ and $p$ a uniform distribution over $[-1,1]$ the distribution looks a follows:

[image]

Is there an analytic way to do these type of calculations?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Function_of_random_variables_and_change_of_variables_in_the_probability_density_function) on wikipedia. Often it is handsome to go for the CDF and then to differentiate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ has uniform distribution on $(-1,1)$ and $f(x)=x^{2}$ then $P(f(X)\leq t)=P(|X|\leq \sqrt t)=\sqrt t$ for $0 <t<1$. Differentiating this we get the density of $f(X)$ as $\frac  1  2 t^{-1/2}$ for $0 <t<1$.

Comment: @drhab I misread the question and thought he was considering uniform distribution on $(0,1)$. Thanks for the correction.